# Initiating a second Random object using the same seed

Tags: java, random, seeding

Using a seed you can get a Random object to spit the same sequence of numbers over and over again. But what if you want to shut down your app, relaunch it and continue spitting numbers from where you left off? Simply initiating a new Random with the same seed starts the sequence again.

So.. Apart from maintaining a list of all calls made to Random and then re-calling them to get back to the same position, is there a better way?

edit:
Zim-Zam has pointed out using Java Serialization to reinitiate the object but I don't want to add a single Java object to my save files which are otherwise entirely XML.

Comment: If you don't mind my asking, why would you want to do it? If you program was initiated with unique (give or take) seed the first time, there is generally no difference in randomness level in continuing previous random sequence and starting completely new one.

Comment: So that one user will have the same experience with my randomly generated content as another user despite their usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. I believe I've found a solution that has stood up to a few tests.

Extending Random gives you access to the protected method next(int). Using this steps the Random position. So by overriding the nextFloat/nextInt/etc methods and incrementing a counter. I can initiate a new Random object, using the same seed and a count and called next() enough times to catch up to the previous instance. Seems to work well and is a nice simple solution.

Thanks to those who answered/commented.

Answer (score 2):

You can serialize your `Random` object with `ObjectOutputStream` to save its state; when you start your program again, deserialize it with `ObjectInputStream` and your `Random` will start where it left off.

Alternatively, [copy-paste the Java Random source code](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/util/Random-source.html) into your own `MyRandom` generator; this will give you a access to the internal workings of the generator so that you can save and restore its state.

Comment: While this is a simple answer, I really don't want to use a single java serialized object in my data-structure which is otherwise entirely XML based. I'll add this to the question.

Comment: Another nice idea but see my answer for something a little simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Or if you don't fancy either serialisation or overriding a fairly complex class, why not:

```
Random mySaveableRandom = new Random();

long bookmark() {
    long bookmark = mySaveableRandom.nextLong();
    mySaveableRandom.setSeed(bookmark);
    return bookmark;
}
...
void startFrom(long bookmark) {
    mySaveableRandom.setSeed(bookmark);
}
```